# Having trouble making a ActionListener

Tags: java, events, awt, actionlistener

I try to make an `ActionListener`, and it gives me a error. I have events imported, and it still doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
send.addActionListener(new jj);

private class jj implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {
        }
    }
```

It gives the 'new jj' a error, and by the class and method, it gives actionListener, and ActionEvent a error.

I need basic help in how to make a actionListener.

Comment: you are missing a `()`

Comment: *"It gives the 'new jj' a error, and by the class and method, it gives actionListener, and ActionEvent a error."* Huh?

Comment: @JasonSperske Please make that an answer so I can up-vote it again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you are missing a `()` after your `new jj`.  Also and this is more of a style point your class names are better capitalized (and a little more descriptive)

Comment: +1 @user2356557 Check out [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) for details

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response, but it just gives me a error by 'addActoinLitener', and still gives me a error by the other 2 places.